# Configure postfix to view catch-all address in mail header

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

I configured catchall for postfix as follows:

```
# vim /etc/postfix/virtual
@example.com  test
```

So if we send mail to `xyzjsdv@example.com` will get delivered to `test@example.com`. But the problem was it always shows the same user name in the mail header `"test@example.com"`. I created a script for checking the mail header, so that I need the particular `user@example` should be display at the mail header, since I need to differentiate all the users. Please help me how to configure the postfix, so that I will get this outcome.

Sudden answers would be appreciated

Comment: What header are you talking about?  An example of what you're seeing would help.

Answer (score 0):

My catch-alls are usually defined like this in the `virtual_mailbox_maps`:

```
me@example.com virtualdomain.com/me
@example.com virtualdomain.com/me
```

The `virtualdomain.com` is defined in `virtual_mailbox_domains`.

This setup doesn't create a forward, but it just drops it in the same place.

To be complete, this is my complete virtual configuration:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 7
virtual_uid_maps = static:8
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
```

The `virtualdomain.com` would then expand to `/var/mail/vhosts/virtualdomain.com`

Don't forget to run `postmap` on the files referenced with `hash`, to create a `.db` file.